# Objective-C: Live Updates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

My team is planning to build an app with live updates or at least daily updates, but we saw that updating an app on itunescoonect takes weeks before it got approved. It is like a news app that updates it contents.

Is it possible to do this live/daily updates? How?
any reference?

Comment: Are you talking about live updating content in your app? Why wouldn't you consider using a HTTP service?

Comment: You should keep the news content on a server. The app should always fetch results from the serve and display.

Answer (score 2):

If it's content you want to update then this should be done with a central server that each device connects to to fetch the new data. Easiest and probably most stable way is to just use a webserver for that and send XML, JSON or similar. This is easy with NSURLRequest or ASIHttpRequest (which seems to be abandoned though).

If you want to change functions and really add new stuff to the app then this can't be done by doing a new iOS app because of what you said, it takes time to aproove a new build. Then your solution would be using a webapp, that just embeds a webpage in the app and whenever you would want to change the app you would just update the website.

Answer (score 2):

As we don't know what do you mean with live updates, here's the general answer ...

**Live Update of Content Only**

Most apps do use JSON ([JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/), [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html), ...) to handle communication between server and application. So, just create some server side stuff to communicate with your application via HTTP[S] and JSON.

Try to avoid XML, REST, ... because it's doable, but it's more work, it's slower, ...

In this way you can easily update content of your application.

**Live Update of Application Binary**

It's not possible, because you need to send it to Apple for approval process which takes some time. On a daily basis = no way.

If you want to do kind of testing builds on a daily basis, you can look at [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com) or [HockeyApp](http://www.hockeyapp.net). Here you can provide daily, hourly, ..., builds to your closed group of users (outside app store). But it's for testing only, etc. First of all you're limited to 100 devices and it's not for end users. Both TF & HA can force users to upgrade your app, can inform user about new version, ...